# Energy loss from original photons to fossil fuel

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, energy-conservation

How would one give a rough back-of-the-envelope calculation of the thermodynamic energy loss of fossil fuels, starting from the original photons hitting prehistoric plants.

The external quantum efficiency of a solar cell is

$$EQE_{solar cell} = \frac{electrons \ out}{photons \ in} $$

What would this be for a fossil fuel?

There must be some exergy loss from the energy of the photons to the exergy available in the fuel. How would one roughly calculate this?

Answer (score 1):

Plant conversion of light energy to chemical energy is pretty low.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photosynthetic_efficiency

Typically crop plants top out at about 2%, but are often lower than that. Crop plants have been put through a long history of selective breeding to get maximum production of biomass. Wild plants put a lot more energy into other things. Such as being able to survive long drought, tolerate being half eaten by herbivores, fighting off fungus or insects, etc. So the plants that produced coal probably were a lot less than 2% efficient.

Here I have to place a big "I don't know" about the efficiency of converting biomass to coal.

Converting fossil fuel to electrical energy is typically 30% to 40% efficient.

https://www.worldcoal.org/reducing-co2-emissions/high-efficiency-low-emission-coal

So overall efficiency from photons to electricity for fossil is something less than 1% max, possibly a lot less if the plants were not particularly efficient.